# determine the nature of eigenvalues of given matrix whose entries are complex number under a given condition

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Q$ be a matrix ($n \times n$), $P$ be its  complex conjugate transpose.    $PQ$ equals identity.

- What can we say about eigenvalues of Q?
- For example - are they    all    real or all complex?
- Are some real and some complex?

My view:

I tried for $2$ by $2$ case. 
I concluded that determinant of the matrix must be $1$ or $-1$.
I solved it for $1$ and $-1$ separately. 
But it became very tough to solve equations. 
I took entries of the form $a+ib$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Q$ be an $n\times n$ matrix, and let $Q^\dagger$ denote its conjugate transpose. Matrices satisfying your condition $Q^\dagger Q = I$ are called [unitary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix). Let $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{C}^n$ be a unit eigenvector for $Q$ under eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then we must have
$$Q\mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{v},$$
and taking the conjugate transpose, also
$$\mathbf{v}^\dagger Q^\dagger = \lambda^*\mathbf{v}^\dagger.$$
Multiplying the two equations together, we have
$$\mathbf{v}^\dagger Q^\dagger Q \mathbf{v} = \lambda \lambda^* \mathbf{v}^\dagger \mathbf{v}=|\lambda|^2\|\mathbf{v}\|^2=|\lambda|^2,$$
where the last equality comes from the fact that $\mathbf{v}$ is a unit eigenvector so that $\|\mathbf{v}\|=1$. Since $Q^\dagger Q = I$, the left hand simplifies to 
$$\mathbf{v}^\dagger Q^\dagger Q \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}^\dagger I \mathbf{v} = \|\mathbf{v}\|^2 = 1.$$
Therefore we conclude that
$$1=\|\lambda\|^2,$$
which means that the eigenvalues of $Q$ must lie on the unit circle, i.e. $\lambda = e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. This is the most general possible constraint, since for any set of such eigenvalues $S=\{e^{i\theta_1}, \cdots ,e^{i\theta_n}\}$, there exists an $n\times n$ unitary matrix with eigenvalues in $S$, namely the diagonal matrix 
$$Q=\mathrm{diag}(e^{i\theta_1},\cdots, e^{i\theta_n}).$$

Comment: Solution is really nice but how do you know it has a unit eigenvector?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then it must have some non-zero eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$. Any scalar multiple of an eigenvector remains an eigenvector, so we can without loss of generality take $\mathbf{v}$ to have unit norm.

Comment: For 2 by 2 case, lamda =1 and -1 ?

Comment: No, the $2\times 2$ case is exactly the same as the $n\times n$ case. The eigenvalues are still arbitrary complex numbers with norm $1$. You can have eigenvalues like $(1+i)/\sqrt{2}$ or $(1+i\sqrt{3})/2$ for example.

Comment: Cnt I suppose 1and -1 to be complex numbers?

Comment: $1$ and $-1$ can also be eigenvalues, I'm sorry if I seemed to suggested otherwise. My point is that they are not the _only_ eigenvalues. There can be others.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. When I was trying to put entries and solving equation, I was totally lost.

Comment: As a general tip, working explicitly with the entries of a matrix is _rarely_ the way to go in linear algebra. Matrices really represent linear maps, and most of the quantities we are interested in (such as eigenvalues for example) cannot be representation dependent. So there's almost always a more "algebraic" way to obtaining the results you need.